# Load on-disk database directly into memory

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Using C# and the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` .NET wrapper (v1.0.117.0). This supports SQLite 3.40.0. The database file is typically under 50 MB, and I'd like to load this into memory. A standard file-backed connection string might be:

```
Data Source=C:\path\to\myDB.db;Version=3;
```

Loading a database file into memory can be done in several stages:

1. Create a blank database using the connection string:

   ```
   Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;
   ```
2. Open a secondary connection (using a standard connection) to the disk file.
3. Read the tables and table schema from the secondary connection.
4. Create all the tables in the in-memory database.
5. Copy data across from the secondary connection into the in-memory database tables.
6. Close the secondary connection.

This works, but is complicated. Am I missing some simple trick? The [SQLite documentation on in-memory databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) is not clear how to load a database file directly into memory. Is it possible to load "this database file" directly into memory in one step?

Comment: Why do you want to load the database in memory?

Comment: there is no built-in method to load an entire disk-based database into memory in one step in SQLite as per my knowledge, but you can create an in-memory database and then use the `backup API` to copy the content of the disk-based database to the in-memory database which is SQLite offer

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: @TikluGanguly: There are many reasons to want to load a database into memory. Two that apply to me: (1) unit testing and (2) for faster read/write performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked it out.

1. Set up two connections.
2. The connection string for the in-memory database (CONNECTION_1) will be `FullUri='file::memory:?cache=shared';`.
3. The connection string for the physical on-disk database (CONNECTION_2) will be `Data Source=C:\\path\\to\\yourDB.db;Version=3;`.
4. Open both connections.
5. Execute the command `VACUUM INTO 'file::memory:?cache=shared';` on CONNECTION_2.
6. Close CONNECTION_2.

The in-memory database is deleted when the connection is closed, so keep CONNECTION_1 open for now.